# Any way to double-click on .PS1 file & open them in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have my_project.ps1 file from which I am activating virtual environment & starting my project.

currently I need to open my powershell then after I need to go to directory where I have saved my .ps1 file & have to open it from powershell only.

Is there any way so that I can double click on .ps1 file & it will open automatically in power shell ?

Answer (score 5):

By design, **double-clicking (opening) `*.ps1` files** from the [Windows [GUI] shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) (in this case: Desktop, File Explorer, and the taskbar, via pinned items) does *not* execute them - instead they're **opened for *editing*** in Notepad or in the PowerShell ISE, depending on the Windows / PowerShell version.

However, since at least Windows 7, the **shortcut menu** for `*.ps1` files contains a **`Run with PowerShell` command**, which *does* invoke the script at hand; this *may* be enough for your purposes, but **this invocation method has limitations** - see the bottom section for details.

#### If you do want to ***redefine* double-clicking / opening so that it *executes* `*.ps1` scripts**, you have two options:

Note:

- It's **best to limit the redefinition to *your* user account**; **otherwise**, other users on the same machine may not expect the modified behavior, which can lead to **unintentional execution of scripts**.
- **For a *given* script (as opposed to *all* `.ps1` files)**, you may **alternatively create a *shortcut file* or *batch file* that launches it**, but that **isn't a general solution**, as you'd have to create a companion file for each and every `.ps1` file you want to run by double-clicking. It does, however, give you full control over the invocation. You can **create shortcut files** *interactively*, via File Explorer, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71783058/45375), or *programmatically*, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47743337/45375).  Similarly, you may **create a companion *batch file*** (`.cmd` or `.bat`) that invokes your script, because batch file *are* executed when double-clicked; e.g., if you place a batch file with the same base name as your `.ps1` script in the same directory (**e.g., `foo.cmd` next to `foo.ps1`**), you can call it from your batch file as follows; `-NoExit` keeps the session open:

  ```bash
  @powershell.exe -NoExit -File "%~dpn0.ps1" %*
  ```

  - Note: If you want to bypass the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) *for this call only*, place a `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` argument before `-File`.
- The **methods below also enable direct execution of a `.ps1` script *from a `cmd.exe` console window***, synchronously, inside the same window. In other words: You can execute, say, script `foo.ps1` directly as such, instead of having to use the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), say, `powershell.exe -File foo.ps1`

##### [*Not recommended*] *GUI* method:

Use File Explorer to make PowerShell execute `.ps1` files by default:

- Right-click on a `.ps1` file and select `Properties`.
- Click on `Change...` next to the `Opens with:` label.
- Click on `More apps` on the bottom of the list and scroll down to `Look for another app on this PC`
- Browse to or paste file path `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and submit.

This method **gives you no control over the specifics of the PowerShell invocation** and has **major limitations**; in effect you'll end up with the following behavior:

- **Major limitations**:

  - **Script paths *with embedded spaces* and `'` chars. cannot be invoked this way**, because, even though such paths are passed with double quotes, the latter are in effect *stripped* by PowerShell, because the path is passed to the *implied* `-Command` parameter, which first strips (unescaped) double quotes from the command line *before* interpreting the result *as PowerShell code* - in which case paths with spaces are seen as *multiple* arguments / paths that contain (an odd number of) `'` cause a syntax error.
  - Note that **if you were to select [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) instead, the CLI of the cross-platform, install-on-demand [*PowerShell (Core) 7+* edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), that problem would *not* arise**, because it defaults to the `-File` parameter - in which case a double-quoted script-file path *is* properly recognized.
  - For the difference between PowerShell CLI calls using `-Command` vs. those using `-File`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375).
  - **Passing arguments is not supported**, which matters if you want to invoke `.ps1` files directly *from `cmd.exe`* and need to pass arguments.
- The redefinition is only in effect for the *current user* - which is probably a good thing, as other users may not expect this change, which can result in unwanted execution of scripts.
- Whatever execution policy is in effect will be honored; e.g., if `Restricted` is in effect, invocation will fail altogether.
- As with the default `Run in PowerShell` command, **the window in which the script runs will *automatically close* when the script ends** - thus, unless the script explicitly prompts the user before exiting, you may not be able to examine its output.

**To exercise more control** over how PowerShell invokes the script including **support for paths *with spaces* and for *passing arguments***, use the programmatic method shown in the **next section**.

---

##### *Programmatic* method:

The code below **modifies the registry** to (re)define the `Open` shortcut-menu command for `*.ps1` files, using the same registry keys that are created when you use the GUI method described above.

You can **run the code as-is** to create a **user-level** file-type definition that:

- uses the executable that runs the current PowerShell session, i.e. `powershell.exe` in *Windows PowerShell*, and `pwsh.exe` in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.
- respects the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) - add an `-ExecutionPolicy` argument to override.
- loads the [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) first - add `-NoProfile` to suppress loading; this is primarily of interest if you're planning to directly invoke `.ps1` files *from `cmd.exe`*, not (just) from File Explorer, in combination with *not* using `-NoExit`.
- runs in the script in its own directory
- keeps the session open after the script exits - remove `-NoExit` to exit the session when the script ends; this is primarily of interest if you're planning to directly invoke `.ps1` files *from `cmd.exe`*, not (just) from File Explorer.

If you requirements differ - if you need different [CLI parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) and/or you want to use `pwsh.exe`, i.e. *PowerShell (Core) 7+* instead - tweak the code first, by modifying the `$cmd = ...` line below; see the comments above it.

```bash
# Specify if the change should apply to the CURRENT USER only, or to ALL users.
# NOTE: If you set this to $true - which is NOT ADVISABLE - 
#       you'll need to run this code ELEVATED (as administrator)
$forAllUsers = $false

# Determine the chosen scope's target registry
$fileTypeName = 'ps1_auto_file'
$targetRegKeys = [ordered] @{
  Extension = "$(('HKCU', 'HKLM')[$forAllUsers]):\Software\Classes\.ps1"
  FileType = "$(('HKCU', 'HKLM')[$forAllUsers]):\Software\Classes\$fileTypeName\shell\open\command" 
} 

# Make sure that the target keys exist.
$targetRegKeys.Values |
  ForEach-Object {
    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $_)) {
      $null = New-Item -Path $_ -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
  }
# Make sure that no Visual Studio Code override is in place.
# (A "VSCode.ps1" entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ps1\OpenWithProgids)
$vsCodeOverrideKey = "$($targetRegKeys.Extension)\OpenWithProgids"
$vsCodeOverrideKey_Abstract = $vsCodeOverrideKey -replace '^.+?:\\Software\\Classes', 'registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT'
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $vsCodeOverrideKey) {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "Removing Visual Studio Code override..."
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $vsCodeOverrideKey
}
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $vsCodeOverrideKey_Abstract) {
  # Implies $forAllUsers -eq $false
  Write-Warning @"

  A HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE version of key $vsCodeOverrideKey_Abstract exists, 
  which makes Visual Studio Code preempt the default action. 
  To remove it, re-run this script with `$forAllUsers set to `$true, 
  which requires ELEVATION, however - and changes the behavior for ALL users.
"@
}

# Specify the command to use when opening / double-clicking *.ps1 scripts:
# As written here:
#   * The script runs in the directory in which it resides.
#   * The profiles are loaded (add -NoProfile to change).
#   * The current execution policy is respected (add -ExecutionPolicy <policy> to override, if possible)
#   * The window stays open after the script exits (remove -NoExit to change)
# For help with all parameters, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe
$cmd = "`"$((Get-Process -Id $PID).Path)`" -nologo -noexit -file `"%1`" %*"

# Write to the registry.
Set-ItemProperty -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $targetRegKeys.Extension -Name '(default)' -Value $fileTypeName
Set-ItemProperty -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $targetRegKeys.FileType  -Name '(default)' -Value $cmd

Write-Verbose -Verbose "$(('User-level', 'Machine-level')[$forAllUsers]) file-type definition for *.ps1 files successfully updated."

# Additionally, make sure that NO USER OVERRIDE preempts the new definition:
# See if a user override established interactively via File Explorer happens to be defined,
# and remove it, if so.
if ($fileExplorerOverrideKey = Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ps1\UserChoice') {  
  Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Removing File Explorer override...'
  # Get the parent key path and the key name
  $parentKeyPath = $fileExplorerOverrideKey.PSParentPath -replace '^.+?::\w+\\' # Remove the 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\' prefix
  $keyName = $fileExplorerOverrideKey.PSChildName
  $key = $null
  try {
    # Open the *parent* key for writing.
    $key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser.OpenSubkey($parentKeyPath, $true)
    # Delete the subkey.
    # !! Due to the specific permissions assigned by File Explorer to the key
    # !! (an additional DENY access-control entry for the current user, for the key itself only, for the 'Set Value' permission),
    # !! using the .DeleteSubKey*Tree*() method fails (Remove-Item implicitly uses this method and therefore fails too)
    # !! However, since there should be no nested subkeys, using .DeleteSubkey() should work fine.
    $key.DeleteSubKey($keyName)
  }
  catch {
    throw
  }
  finally {
    if ($key) { $key.Close()}
  }
}
```

---

##### *Explanation* of the *predefined* `Run in PowerShell` shortcut-menu command:

*Update*:

- The following applies to **Windows 10 only**.
- In Windows 11, the relevant registry key is now `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\Windows.PowerShell.Run\Command`, and the command is properly defined with the `-File` CLI parameter, albeit without any attempt to set the execution policy on demand - however, the command still does not keep the windows of scripts invoked this way open after they terminate; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77809254/45375) for a solution.

It is defined in registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\shell\0\Command` as follows:

```bash
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'"
```

- This command is *flawed* in that it **breaks with script-file paths that happen to contain `'` characters.**
- **Unless execution policy `AllSigned` is in effect** - in which case only *signed* scripts can be executed but are executed *without prompting*  - the command attempts to set the execution policy for the invoked process to `Bypass`, which means that ***any* script can be executed, but only after the user responds to a *confirmation prompt* beforehand** (irrespective of whether the script is signed or not, and whether it was downloaded from the web or not).

  - At least in earlier Windows 7 releases / PowerShell versions, the command was *misdefined*<sup>[1]</sup> in a way that effectively ignored the attempt to set the process' execution policy, which meant that whatever execution policy was persistently configured applied - and no confirmation prompt was shown.
- **Unless the targeted script explicitly pauses to wait for user input before exiting, the window in which the script will *close automatically*** when the script finishes, so you may not get to see its output.
- The targeted script **executes in the directory in which it is located** as the working directory (current location)

---

<sup>[1] The earlier, broken command definition was `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-file" "%1" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne AllSigned) { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }"`, which meant what anything after `-file "%1"` was passed as *arguments* to file `"%1"` instead of the intended execution of the commands following `-Command`; additionally - a moot point - the `AllSigned` operand would have need to be quoted.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### **To execute a PS1 file by double-click (to run)**

Make a shortcut for the file and set the target to this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "C:\Temp\MyPowershellScript.ps1"
```

Replace the second directory (the one in quotes) with the location of your script.

---

### **To read a PS1 file by double-click (to edit)**

Same as above, but target ISE instead, as that will force it into edit mode.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe "C:\Temp\MyPowershellScript.ps1"
```

Comment: I suggest clarifying that your method doesn't generally change how double-clicking `.ps1` files behaves, but instead shows how to execute a _given, single_ `.ps1` file _via a dedicated shortcut file_ that _must explicitly be created_ for it. Note that your command will break with file paths that have _spaces_ - unless you prepend `-File` (to also support drag and drop, append `%*`)

Comment: As an aside regarding the ISE: It's [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)

Answer (score 0):

Server 2012 and newer by default do not associate the .PS1 file extension with the PowerShell executable; rather, they default to open .PS1 files with notepad by default for security reasons.

If you have access, you need to change the file association through the 'default programs' in your control panel for the .PS1 files to execute by double clicking.

Also be aware that you may have to change your execution policy to get particular scripts to run.

Also, as it sounds like this script might be a core automation, you can execute scripts from in another one with either of these, without the need to change the active working directory:
Invoke-Item ""
& ''

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the registry values so that the .ps1 scripts are executed with double click or with "Run with PowerShell" from any position without problem, even with paths with multiple consecutive spaces and with apostrophes:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ps1]
@="Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -NoExit -Command \"Set-Location -LiteralPath \\\"%V\\\"\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\Powershell\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -NoExit -Command \"Set-Location -LiteralPath \\\"%V\\\"\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Powershell\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -NoExit -Command \"Set-Location -LiteralPath \\\"%V\\\"\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -File \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\0\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -File \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\Edit\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell_ise.exe\" -File \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell]
"ExecutionPolicy"="RemoteSigned"
```