# PowerShell removes multiple consecutive whitespaces when I pass arguments to a nested Start-Process command

Tags: windows-10, escaping, whitespace, start-process, powershell-5.1

This powershell code works fine:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command {Start-Process -FilePath wscript.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '"C:\Users\TestAccount\Desktop\cartella  con  spazi\test.vbs" "/CurrentDirectory:C:\Users\TestAccount\Desktop\Cartella  con  spazi" "/AppData:C:\Users\TestAccount\AppData\Roaming"'}
```

But when I enter the complete command, powershell leaves only one space between the words but in my path there are two consecutive ones:

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -WorkingDirectory "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE" -Credential $credential -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -Command & {Start-Process -FilePath wscript.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '\`"C:\Users\TestAccount\Desktop\cartella  con  spazi\test.vbs\`" \`"/CurrentDirectory:C:\Users\TestAccount\Desktop\Cartella  con  spazi\`" \`"/AppData:C:\Users\TestAccount\AppData\Roaming\`"'}"
```

Same error with this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -WorkingDirectory "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE" -Credential $credential -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -Command Start-Process -FilePath wscript.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '\`"C:\Users\TestAccount\Desktop\cartella  con  spazi\test.vbs\`" \`"/CurrentDirectory:C:\Users\TestAccount\Desktop\Cartella  con  spazi\`" \`"/AppData:C:\Users\TestAccount\AppData\Roaming\`"'"
```

This is the error message:

[image]

As you can see, in the error message the path contains only one space between words, while in the code I have correctly entered two consecutive ones.

This is the code to enter the credentials (just before the line that gives an error):

```
$username = 'Username'
$password = 'Password'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
```

I've been getting a single line of code to work properly for days but without success.
Those example paths I entered are actually variables (with an indefinite number of consecutive spaces) and therefore by enclosing -ArgumentList in single quotes, the variables are not expanded.
You can adopt the strategy you think is most appropriate to help me.
Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
Powershell Version: 5.1.19041.1237 (Integrated in Windows 10).

UPDATE:

@mklement0 There is the problem that in reality the line in question contains an expandable variable:

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -WorkingDirectory "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE" -Credential $credential -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList @"
-NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -FilePath wscript.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '\"$PWD\test.vbs\" \"/CurrentDirectory:$PWD\" \"/AppData:$env:APPDATA\"'"
"@
```

so if the path contains single quotes, the line goes in error.

UPDATE 2:

@mklement0 Your solution has stopped working since I put it in a script, which is what I need, with the following error message:

[image]

Comment: What if you escape the spaces too: ``cartella\` \` con\` \` spazi`` ?

Comment: Those example paths I entered are actually variables and therefore the solution must expect an indefinite number of consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: This answer addresses the `Start-Process` problem; for the *unrelated* problem with `.ps1` files whose paths have spaces in them  failing to run when they are double-clicked in File Explorer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245206/45375).

---

Try the following, with the **arguments passed *verbatim***:

```bash
Start-Process `
  -FilePath powershell.exe `
  -WorkingDirectory "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE" `
  -Credential $credential `
  -WindowStyle Hidden `
  -ArgumentList @'
    -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -FilePath wscript.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '\"C:\Users\TestAccount\Desktop\cartella  con  spazi\test.vbs\" \"/CurrentDirectory:C:\Users\TestAccount\Desktop\Cartella  con  spazi\" \"/AppData:C:\Users\TestAccount\AppData\Roaming\"'"
'@
```

- The `-Command` argument is enclosed in `"..."` in order to preserve the command-internal spaces as-is.
- The *embedded* `"` characters in the command string are escaped as `\"`
- The outer `-ArgumentList` uses a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to simplify the embedded quoting.

  - The *verbatim* form (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`) is used here; use the _expandable form, `@"<newline>...<newline>"@`, if you need string interpolation (the ability to embed variable references and expressions) - see next section.
- While PowerShell-*internally* it is `` ` ``, the backtick, that serves as the escape character, PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) expects `"` characters to be `\`-escaped *on the command line*, so as to conform to the most widely used escaping convention.

  - The cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+* edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now also accepts `""` as an alternative to `\"`, another common convention on Windows.
  - While you may situationally have to *combine* the two escaping approaches, i.e. to use `` `\" `` in order to quote a `"` *first* for the CLI and *then* for PowerShell-internal use, in the context of interpreting a `-Command` argument, this isn't needed in the command above, because the inner `-ArgumentList` argument uses *single*-quoting, inside of which `"` can be be used as-is.

---

***Generalized* solution, with arguments provided *via variables*:**

The assumption is that the variable whose value are to be used are named `$dir1`, `$dir2`, and `$dir3` (and that their values have no embedded `"` chars., but `"` aren't supported in file-system paths on Windows anyway).

```bash
Start-Process `
  -FilePath powershell.exe `
  -WorkingDirectory "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE" `
  -Credential $credential `
  -WindowStyle Hidden `
  -ArgumentList @"
    -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -FilePath wscript.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '\"$($dir1 -replace "'", "''")\" \"/CurrentDirectory:$($dir2 -replace "'", "''")\" \"/AppData:$($dir3 -replace "'", "''")\"'"
"@
```

- The *interpolating* form of a here-string (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) must now be used for the outer `-ArgumentList` argument.
- Since the variable values are interpolated inside what `powershell.exe` will see as a single-quoted string (`'...'`), any `'` characters embedded in the variable values must be escaped as `''`, which is what `-replace "'", "''"` in the embedded `$(...)` [subexpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) does.

---

#### **Optional reading: Troubleshooting calls to external programs:**

It can be difficult to diagnose problems with calls to external programs, especially in a nested call such as this. The following is a *Windows* solution; see the bottom for a *Unix* solution.

##### Preparation: Create helper executable `echoArgsPause.exe`:

The following creates a helper executable, `echoArgsPause.exe`, which echoes the full command line it was called with, as well as the individual arguments it has parsed the command line into, and then waits for a keystroke.

Note:

- As a .NET-based `*.exe`, it uses .NET's rules for command-line parsing, which in turn is based on [Microsoft's C/C++ conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-160#parsing-c-command-line-arguments). Unfortunately, not all executables are *guaranteed* to use the same conventions. And, indeed, the WSH CLIs (`cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe`) do not support *embedded* `"` characters in arguments, for instance.
- **Run the code from *Windows PowerShell***, because the executable must be compiled via .NET Framework, not .NET (Core), because only the former reports the true, raw command line via `[Environment]::CommandLine`.
- For later reuse, place the resulting `.\echoArgsPause.exe` file in a directory in your PATH (in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`).
- To create a variant that doesn't wait for a keystroke, remove the `Console.Write("Press a key to exit: ");` and `Console.ReadKey(true);` lines and change `-OutputAssembly .\echoArgsPause.exe` to, say, `-OutputAssembly ./echoArgs.exe`

```bash
Add-Type -OutputType ConsoleApplication -OutputAssembly .\echoArgsPause.exe -TypeDefinition @'
  using System;
  static class ConsoleApp {
    static int Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("\nraw: [{0}]\n", Environment.CommandLine);
      for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i) {
          Console.WriteLine("arg #{0}: [{1}]", i, args[i]);
      }
      Console.Write("Press a key to exit: ");
      Console.ReadKey(true);
      return 0;
    }
  }
'@
```

##### Use of `echoArgsPause.exe` to troubleshoot a call

- The following, self-contained sample code uses a simplified version of your command, and uses the `echoArgsPause.exe` in lieu of your target executable (`wscript.exe`) to print the command line and the parsed arguments.

```bash
# Specify the full path to the helper executable.
# Here I'm assuming it is in the current dir.
$echoArgsPausePath = "$($PWD.ProviderPath)\echoArgsPause.exe"

# Sample variable values.
$dir1='c:\temp''o  1'
$dir2='c:\temp   2'
$dir3='c:\temp    3'

# Call your command, with echoArgsPause.exe in lieu
# of the target executable (wscript.exe)
Start-Process `
  -FilePath powershell.exe `
  -WorkingDirectory "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE" `
  -WindowStyle Hidden `
  -ArgumentList @"
  -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -FilePath "$echoArgsPausePath" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '\"$($dir1 -replace "'", "''")\" \"/CurrentDirectory:$($dir2 -replace "'", "''")\" \"/AppData:$($dir3 -replace "'", "''")\"'"
"@
```

##### On *Unix*-like platforms:

Unix-like platforms have *no* process-level command line; instead, they are launched via an array of *verbatim* arguments.

Therefore, a simple solution is to use the standard `printf` utility to list each argument received on its own line; e.g.:

```bash
printf %s\n foo 'c:\temp''o  1' '3" of snow'
```

Output up to PowerShell (Core) 7.2.x (broken! note the missing `"`):

```bash
foo
c:\temp'o  1
3 of snow
```

Output in v7.3.0+:

```bash
foo
c:\temp'o  1
3" of snow
```

The 7.2.x behavior reveals a long-standing bug with respect to passing arguments with embedded double quotes, which was fixed in 7.3.0; it is in effect *by default* on Unix-like platforms, but will be *opt-in* on Windows, at some point post-v7.3.1 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).

Comment: So there!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69846632/the-powershell-code-works-when-run-from-the-powershell-command-prompt-but-not-wh

Comment: Thanks, @MarioPalumbo. As stated in a comment I left on your later post, a robust solution for double-clicking `.ps1` files from File Explorer can be found in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245206/45375).

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution without Here-String:

```
$username = 'Username'
$password = 'Password'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -WorkingDirectory "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE" -Credential $credential -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -Command `"Start-Process -FilePath wscript -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '\`"$((Get-Location).Path -replace "'", "''")\test.vbs\`" \`"/CurrentDirectory:$((Get-Location).Path -replace "'", "''")\`" \`"/AppData:$($env:APPDATA -replace "'", "''")\`"'`""
```