# What is the difference between the escape backtick "`" and backslash "\" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, escaping

I know that both are used in PowerShell but for different contexts.

On the internet there is a paucity of information on this topic and the only site that talks about it (without making me understand the concept) is:
https://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm

I am a beginner with PowerShell, I am recently approaching it.
A use case of the `\` escape came up in the answer to this other topic of mine:
[PowerShell removes multiple consecutive whitespaces when I pass arguments to a nested Start-Process command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827746/powershell-removes-multiple-consecutive-whitespaces-when-i-pass-arguments-to-a-n)

Is there anyone who can explain to me in detail the difference between the escape backtick `` ` `` and backslash `\` in PowerShell, with examples and use cases?

At least one source is welcome, but it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[vonPryz's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) covers the PowerShell-*internal* angle well; let me attempt a systematic summary that includes the PowerShell *CLI* angle, as well as passing arguments with embedded `"` to external programs:

***Inside* a PowerShell session**, the ***only* escape character is `` ` ``** (the so-called **backtick**), in the following contexts:

- Inside an [*expandable* string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`, double quoted), but *not* inside a [*verbatim* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) (`'...'`, single-quoted); for the supported escape *sequences*, see the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic:

  ```bash
  # " must be escaped; escape sequence `n expands to a newline.
  "3`" of`nrain"
  ```
- In unquoted *command arguments*:

  ```bash
  # > must be escaped to write verbatim 'a>b', 
  # since outside a quoted string an unescaped > is a redirection.
  Write-Output a`>b
  ```
- For [*line-continuations*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235993/1175496):

  ```bash
  # Spread the Get-Date call across two lines.
  # Important: ` must be the *very last char* on the line.
  Get-Date `
    -Year 2525
  ```
- Note: Various *subsystems*, whether PowerShell-specific or not, may have their own escaping rules, such as `\` in [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) and `` ` `` in [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards). Since arguments to those subsystems are delivered *via PowerShell strings*, it's best to use *verbatim* string literals, so as to avoid confusion between PowerShell's own string interpolation and what the target subsystem ends up seeing; e.g. `'A $50 fine.' -match '\$50'` (`\` is needed to treat regex metacharacter `$` literally).

---

**When PowerShell is called *from the outside, via its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)*, *different* rules apply**, possibly *in addition*:

**In order to adhere to widely used convention for CLIs** (command-line interfaces, programs that accept arguments via a command line) on Windows:

- In calls to **[`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**, the ***Windows PowerShell* CLI**, **`"` characters must be escaped *with a backslash* - i.e. as `\"` - in order to be *preserved*** during parsing *of the original command line*.
- **[`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh)**, the CLI of the cross-platform, install-on-demand **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+* edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, now commendably ***alternatively* accepts `""`**<sup>[1]</sup> in lieu of `\"`, which makes calls from `cmd.exe` more robust. To get the same robustness in *Windows PowerShell* - from `cmd.exe` only - use **`"^""`** (sic).
  Note that - unlike `\"` - these escape sequences only work *inside an (unescaped) `"..."` string* (e.g., `pwsh.exe -c " ""you & I"" "` or `powershell.exe -c " "^""you & I"^"" "`

By contrast, ***unescaped* `"`** have *syntactic* function on the command line and tell PowerShell where the boundaries between arguments are; these `"` instances are ***removed* during command-line parsing**.

This ensures that outside callers that merely want to **invoke a PowerShell *script file* (`.ps1`) with arguments, using the `-File` parameter**, can use the conventional syntax and needn't special-case calls to PowerShell's CLI.

However, if you **pass a string containing *PowerShell code* to the CLI, using the `-Command` parameter**, what PowerShell ends up interpreting obviously must be syntactically valid PowerShell code.

*Caveat*: If you specify neither `-Command` nor `-File`:

- `powershell.exe` defaults to `-Command`
- `pwsh.exe` now defaults to `-File`

For the differences between `-File` and `-Command` calls and when to use which, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375).

If you use `-Command`, there are *two*, sequential parsing stages:

- The *command-line* parsing stage, where syntactic (unescaped) `"` are *removed*, and escaped `\"` (or `""`) turn into literal `"`.
- The *result* of this stage is *then* parsed *as PowerShell code*, as it would be from inside a PowerShell session.

Therefore, **you may situationally have to *combine* `\` and `` ` ``-escaping**; e.g. (call from `cmd.exe`):

```bash
C:>powershell.exe -Command " \"3`\" of snow as of $(Get-Date)\" "

3" of snow as of 11/04/2021 14:13:41
```

Note the use of `` `\" `` in order to make PowerShell see `` `" ``, i.e. a properly escaped `"` inside a `"..."` string, *after command-line parsing*.

Alternatively, depending on the specifics of the command(s) you pass to `-Command`, using **embedded `'...'` quoting *may* be an option**, which simplifies matters, because `'` chars. don't require escaping:

```bash
C:>powershell.exe -Command " '3\" of snow as of today.' "

3" of snow as of today.
```

Given that `'...'` strings in PowerShell are [*verbatim* strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), use of `'...'` is only an option if you don't require string interpolation (such as the `$(Get-Date)` subexpression in the prior example).

---

**Escaping `"` when calling external programs *from* PowerShell:**

As a *shell*, it is PowerShell's job to pass the arguments that were passed based on *its* syntax rules to a target executable, so that the verbatim values that result from PowerShell's parsing are passed in a way that makes the target executable see them as such. In other words: PowerShell should perform any required escaping *automatically*, behind the scenes. (Unlike `cmd.exe`, PowerShell cannot just pass its own argument syntax through as-is, because external CLIs cannot be expected to understand `'...'` strings (single-quoting) or `` ` ``-escaping).

To use a simply example: Passing `'3" of snow'` *should* be passed as `"3\" of snow"` behind the scenes, based on the most widely used escaping convention.

Sadly, **up to PowerShell 7.2.x**, this is *not* the case, and **embedded `"` characters in arguments for *external programs* must *additionally, manually* be `\`-escaped** in order to be passed through properly.

- This **has been fixed in PowerShell 7.3, with selective exceptions on Windows** - see the new [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing)

```bash
# Broken behavior up to PS v7.2.x

PS> cmd /c echo '{ "foo": "bar" }'
"{ "foo": "bar" }"  # !! Embedded " aren't escaped.

PS> choice.exe /d Y /t 0 /m '{ "foo": "bar" }'
{ foo: bar } [Y,N]?Y  # !! When parsed by an executable, 
                      # !! embedded " are effectively LOST.

# Manual escaping required.
PS> choice.exe /d Y /t 0 /m '{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }'
{ "foo": "bar" } [Y,N]?Y  # OK
```

This bug has existed since v1, and has never been fixed so as to avoid breaking existing *workarounds*.

---

<sup>[1] Inside PowerShell, in `"..."` strings only, you may also use `""` to escape an embedded `"`, as an alternative to `` `" ``</sup>

Comment: Wow, explained in a masterly way! This is the explanation I was looking for, thank you very much. This will contribute in a not indifferent way to the help of the users.

Comment: v7.3 was released. The fix does not requires opt-in.

Comment: Thanks, @GerardoGrignoli - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

The backtick `` ` `` is used as the [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.1) in Powershell. That is, escaping quotes, tabs and whatnot. Unlike in many other environments, Powershell's newline is `` `n ``, not `\n`. This has the benefit of simplifying paths, since those use backslash in Windows.

As for a practical example, in many programming languages one needs to escape the backslashes in paths. If you have an application located at

```
c:\program files\newApplication\myApp.exe
```

Its path must be written as

```
c:\\program files\\newApplication\\myApp.exe
```

The double-backslash notation means that there is actaully a backslash, not a metacharacter such as tab or newline. Note that the path contains `\newApplication`. Now, `\n` usually means a newline, but it clearly isn't the case. The file does not reside in

```
c:\program files\
ewApplication\myApp.exe
```

after all, doesn't it?

The escaping is not needed in Powershell, as the backslash doesn't have special meaning by itself. When Powershell sees `c:\program files\newApplication\myApp.exe`, it doesn't assign any special meaning to the forementioned `\n` part, it is just a string literal.

The backslash `\` is used as the escape character in regular expressions and to signify metacharacters. That is, to match a literal `*` in regex, it must be escaped, lest it means the Kleene star (zero or more matches).

Comment: But it was necessary in the answer to this other topic of mine, and it is not a case among those you have listed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827746/powershell-removes-multiple-consecutive-whitespaces-when-i-pass-arguments-to-a-n

Comment: That's because the `\"` escapes are used to pass values to the wscript VBScript interpreter via invoking a new process.

Comment: But wscript doesn't require \ backslashes when passing parameters, neither calling it directly from PowerShell nor from cmd.
Can you explain yourself better?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo This is because most external programs including PowerShell.exe rely on the CommandLineToArgvW Windows API function to process command line arguments. That requires the `\"` syntax. So when calling an executable from PowerShell, you have to consider the PowerShell layer of escaping (so that PowerShell parses correctly before calling the program) and the called program's required escaping.