# How can use a PowerShell script to run the Terraform CLI and pass a variable of type map?

Tags: windows, unix, terraform, powershell-core

The variable in the Terraform file (`infrastructure.tf`) is declared like this:

```
variable "tags" {
  type = map(string)
}
```

This is the PowerShell code that executes the `terraform` command-line program with the [`plan`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan) command:

```
$command = "plan"
$options = @(
    "'--var=tags={a:\`"b\`"}'"
    "--out=path/to/out.tfplan"
)

Write-Host terraform,$command,$options

& terraform $command $options
```

The `Write-Host` command's output is:

```
terraform plan '--var=tags={a:\"b\"}' --out=path/to/out.tfplan
```

If I copy paste that into an interactive PowerShell 7.2 (`pwsh`) session then it works. But the `& terraform` command fails with this error:

> Error: Too many command line arguments
>
> To specify a working directory for the plan, use the global -chdir flag.

I know the Terraform documentation for the `plan` command [warns against using PowerShell](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#input-variables-on-the-command-line) to run the command, due to quoting issues (emphasis mine):

> PowerShell **on Windows** cannot correctly pass literal quotes to external programs, so we do not recommend using Terraform with PowerShell when you are on Windows. Use Windows Command Prompt instead.

Unfortunately they don't specify if they mean Windows PowerShell 5.1 included in Windows (`powershell.exe`), or also PowerShell 7.2 running on Windows (`pwsh`). But with `pwsh` it is clearly possible to run the `plan` command in an interactive PowerShell session (I am using macOS, but some others use Windows) and pass literal quotes to an external program. It just seems that running the same command from a .ps1 file does not work.

Since our whole dev/ops tooling is PowerShell-based, I'd like to know: is this possible?

Because if it is not, then we will have to work around this limitation.

Edit:
Some things I've tried:

- Use splatting for `$options` (e.g. `@options`)
- Add the stop-parsing token (e.g. `--%`) as the first item in `$options` (that token is actually ["only intended for use on Windows platforms"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token))
- Many variations of single/double quotes
- Remove the `\` (I am not actually sure why this seems required, the [`map`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#map) literal syntax is either `{"x"="y"}` or `{x:"y"}`), but without the `\` copy-pasting the printed command line in an interactive PowerShell also does not work.

Comment: Give `& terraform $command @options` a shot

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MathiasR.Jessen, unfortunately just using the splat syntax does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: I've added the `[powershell-core]` tag. I'm unclear on whether you need a _Windows_ solution, a _Unix_ solution, or both. Please add the relevant tags. Note that your original approach cannot work, because the `'` characters would become a _literal part of your argument_.

Comment: In case it helps with seeing how Terraform is understanding the command line that PowerShell built, you can set the environment variable `TF_LOG=INFO` to make Terraform generate some internal logs. Early on in that output should be a line starting with `CLI command args:`, followed by a Go syntax representation of the sequence of arguments Terraform understood.

Comment: For what you're trying here to work, Terraform must see the entire sequence `-var=tags={a={"b"}}` as a single element in that sequence. Terraform is showing the strings in quotes, so there will be one extra level of backslash escaping just to represent the Go quoted string syntax.

Comment: Terraform on Windows expects a command line using the same syntax as would be expected by the Visual C++ Runtime Library. Those rules are summarized here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments

Comment: PowerShell itself constructs the final command line based on its own rules, and I'm not familiar enough with it to say how to force PowerShell to generate quoting that follows those rules, but hopefully those are helpful hints at least on what _Terraform_ is expecting, and so you can find out how to convince PowerShell to generate a command line in that syntax.

Comment: I overcomplicated the answer: what it boils down to: omit the embedded `'...'`, and it should work, on all platforms - except in 7.3.0 and 7.3.1, where you additionally need `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'`. Please see the tl;dr section I've added to the top of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Omit the *embedded* enclosing `'...'` around `--var=...`, because they will become a *literal* part of your argument.
- The - unfortunate - need to *manually* `\`-escape the embedded `"` instances, even though PowerShell itself does not need it, is the result of a long-standing bug that was finally fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7.3.0; in 7.3.0 and up to at least 7.3.1, the fix is in effect *by default*, which breaks the solution below, and therefore requires `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'`; however, it looks like the fix will become *opt-in* in the future, i.e. the old, broken behavior (`Legacy`) will become the default again - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).
- Using [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) to inspect the arguments isn't a valid test, because, as a *PowerShell* command, it isn't subject to the same rules as an *external program*.

  - For ways to troubleshoot argument-passing to *external programs*, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832150/45375).

```bash
$command = "plan"
$options = @(
    "--var=tags={a:\`"b\`"}" # NO embedded '...' quoting
    "--out=path/to/out.tfplan"
)

# No point in using Write-Host

& { # Run in a child scope to localize the change to $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing

  # Note: Only needed if you're (also) running on PowerShell 7.3+
  $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'

  & terraform $command $options
}
```

---

#### How to control the exact process command line on Windows / pass arguments with embedded double quotes properly on Unix:

Note: The solution above relies on PowerShell's old, broken behavior, and while it works in the case at hand, a fully robust and less conceptually confusing solution requires more explicit control over how the arguments are passed, as shown below.

---

##### A *cross-edition*, *cross-version*, *cross-platform* solution:

Assuming that `terraform` must see `--var=tags={a:\"b\"}` on its process command line on Windows, i.e. needs to see the argument as *verbatim* `--var=tags={a:"b"}` *after parsing its command line*, **combine `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token), with [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)**, which gives you **full control over how the Windows process command line is built behind the scenes**:

```bash
$command = "plan"
$options = @(
    '--%'
    '--var=tags={a:\"b\"}'
    '--out=path/to/out.tfplan'
)

& { # Run in a child scope to localize the change to $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing

  # !! Required in v7.3.0 and up to at least v7.3.1, due to a BUG.
  $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'

  & terraform $command @options
}
```

This creates the following process command line behind the scenes on Windows (using an example `terraform` path):

```bash
C:\path\to\terraform.exe plan  --var=tags={a:\"b\"} --out=path/to/out.tfplan
```

Note:

- **In PowerShell (Core) 7.3.0 and at least up to 7.3.1, `--%` is *broken* by default**, in that its proper functioning is mistakenly tied to value of the v7.3+ [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing) preference variable; thus, (temporarily) setting `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'` is required, as shown above - see [GitHub issue #18664](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18664) for the bug report.
- Even though `--%` is primarily intended for *Windows*, it **works on *Unix*-like platforms too, *as long as you use the [Microsoft C/C++ command-line syntax rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args#parsing-c-command-line-arguments)*** to formulate the arguments; specifically, this means:

  - only use `"` characters for quoting (with syntactic function)
  - use `\` *only* to escape `"` chars.
- While you can use `--%` *without* splatting, doing so comes with severe limitations - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

---

##### A simpler, but *Windows-only* cross-edition, cross-version solution:

Calling via `cmd /c` also gives you control over how the command line is constructed:

```bash
$command = "plan"
$options = @(
    '--var=tags={a:\"b\"}'
    '--out=path/to/out.tfplan'
)

cmd /c "terraform $command $options"
```

Note: This is often more convenient than `--%`, but suboptimal, because:

- The intermediary `cmd.exe` call creates extra overhead.
- `%` characters may be interpreted by `cmd.exe`, and, in unquoted arguments, additional metacharacters such as `&` and `^` - preventing that requires extra effort.

---

##### A *v7.3+* cross-platform solution:

Relying on PowerShell's corrected behavior in v7.3+ (no need for manual `\`-escaping anymore) requires setting `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` to `'Standard'`.

- Note: If you target *only* Unix-like platforms, that isn't necessary.

```bash
$command = "plan"
$options = @(
    '--var=tags={a:"b"}' # Note: NO \-escaping of " required anymore.
    '--out=path/to/out.tfplan'
)

& { # Run in a child scope to localize the change to $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing

  # Necessary on Windows only.
  $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Standard'

  & terraform $command $options
}
```

Note: On Windows, this creates a slightly different process command line than the solutions above; notably, `--var=tags={a:\"b\"}` is *enclosed in `"..."` as a whole*; however, well-behaved CLIs should parse this as verbatim `--var=tags={a:"b"}` too, whether enclosed in `"..."` or not.

```bash
C:\path\to\terraform.exe plan  "--var=tags={a:\"b\"}" --out=path/to/out.tfplan
```

Comment: Amazing summary and background information, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MichielvanOosterhout; my pleasure. Unfortunately, argument-passing to external programs is a mess in PowerShell, and the recent attempt to fix it has created even more confusion. I've proposed a way forward that doesn't rely on a preference variable [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18660#issuecomment-1349795248), but its chances of getting adopted aren't good.