# View final output of & with parameters

Tags: powershell

When I use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#call-operator-) (`&`) w/ parameters, how do I see the final command executed?

```
$FilePath = 'C:\some path\blah.exe'
$ArgumentList = @(
    '"blah 1"'
    '--blah2'
)
& $FilePath $ArgumentList
```

Powershell doesn't show me the final command issued to the operating system.  I must be doing something wrong but I can't see what that is!

I would expect something like this:

> & "C:\some path\blah.exe" "blah 1" "--blah2"

Comment: Where are you expecting to see this? PowerShell does not work like cmd `ECHO` when running .bat file scripts. This might be helpful. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/tracing-the-execution-of-a-powershell-script/

Comment: As an aside: In PowerShell (Core) 7.3+, `'"blah 1"'` is (fortunately) no longer placed as verbatim `"blah 1"` on the process command line, but as `"\"bah bar\""`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).

Answer (score 1):

> Powershell doesn't show me the final command issued to the operating system.

The purpose of **`&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), is *invocation*, and it **offers *no* diagnostic output**.

- Note that using `&` is no different from *direct* invocation of executables specified via *literal, unquoted* paths, e.g, `C:\some-path\blah.exe ...`: `&` is only ever needed for *syntactic* reasons, namely to effect direct invocation of commands (executables) expressed via *quoted strings* and/or involving *variable references* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for background info.

---

Note:

- The **following applies to *Windows* only**, because only there do child processes receive a *command line* string that *encodes all arguments* which the child process has to parse.
- On *Unix*-like platforms, child process receive an *array* of *verbatim* arguments, so whatever arguments *PowerShell* sees after *it* parsed the original command line are passed on as-is.<sup>[1]</sup>  However, the `Trace-Command` approach below may still be helpful in understanding how *PowerShell* parsed the arguments.

To **examine the *raw process command line* that an *external program* call receives**, you must **use a *helper executable*** that is capable of echoing the raw process command line:

- If you use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), you can use `choco install echoargs -y` from an elevated session to install `echoargs.exe`, which shows the raw command line that PowerShell builds behind the scenes, and how (most) external programs parse it into arguments.

  ```
  echoArgs $ArgumentList
  ```
- Alternatively - via Windows PowerShell - you can compile such a utility ad hoc: see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832150/45375), which also shows how to create such a utility for *Unix* platforms.

A **limited alternative** in **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** is to use **[`Trace-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command)**:

- `Trace-Command -PSHOST -Name ParameterBinding { & $FilePath $ArgumentList }`
- This *may* show you the *raw* command line (excluding the *executable*), in a *single* `BIND argument [...]` output line, namely under the following conditions:

  - in v7.2-: always
  - in v7.3+:

    - By default ([`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing) `= 'Windows'`): only for those executables listed in the linked help topic as continuing to use the old, broken legacy behavior, notably `cmd.exe` / batch files.
    - If `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'` is set: for *all* external programs.
    - If `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Standard'` is set (the default on *Unix*): for *no* external programs.
- In the event that the raw command line *isn't* shown, you'll see *argument-individual* `BIND cmd line arg [...] to position [<n>]` lines, which simply reflect how *PowerShell* parsed each argument.

  - These arguments are then handed *verbatim* to the underlying .NET API, via the (.NET (Core)-only) [`.ArgumentList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList) property of `[System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]`) type:

    - On *Unix*, .NET relays these argument *as-is*.
    - On *Windows*, it translates them to a raw process command line based on the on [Microsoft's C/C++ command-line parsing rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args#parsing-c-command-line-arguments).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for background information.

---

<sup>[1] This applies to [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) **v7.3+**. Earlier versions passed arguments based on broken legacy rules. Those rules are still available on an opt-in basis via `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375) for background.</sup>