# How do I run an executable within a GitLab CI/CD pipeline with a PowerShell shell

Tags: powershell, gitlab, continuous-integration

I'm using curl to succcessfully upload a file to Artifactory using the following commend in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline definition:

```
'& "$CURL_PATH" "-verbose" "-u$ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIAL" "-T$PUBLISH_FOLDER\$($TARGET_PROJECT)_$($FILE_VERSION)_Production.zip" "$ARTIFACTORY_URL/$($TARGET_PROJECT)_$($FILE_VERSION)_Production.zip"'
```

which works perfectly fine.  But when I plug the same into a PowerShell foreach cmdlet, like so:

```
$zipFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Filter "$($TARGET_PROJECT)_$($FILE_VERSION)*" -Path "$PUBLISH_FOLDER")
$zipFiles | ForEach-Object { '& "$CURL_PATH" "-verbose" "-u$ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIAL" "-T$($_.FullName)" "$ARTIFACTORY_URL/$($_.Name)"' }
```

then nothing happens, I'm guessing because the ForEach script block is being interpreted as a string?

I've also tried:

```
$zipFiles | ForEach-Object { & "$CURL_PATH" -verbose "-u$ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIAL" "-T$($_.FullName)" "$ARTIFACTORY_URL/$($_.Name)" }
```

but that results in *502 Bad Gateway* errors.

I'm relatively new to GitLab CI/CD pipelines so I guess the issue is with my understanding of how the gitlab-ci.yml file is parsed by the  GitLab Runner and then passed to the underlying PowerShell shell for execution.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Your first attempt predictably won't work, because `'...'` is a PowerShell verbatim string literal that is simply printed as-is. The second attempt looks OK in principle - are all the variables set as expected?

Comment: To troubleshoot calls to external programs by examining what the verbatim process command line (on Windows) / the verbatim arguments are (on Unix), you can use the techniques from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349130/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 the first attempt does work and the file is uploaded to Artifactory.

Comment: I meant the first attempt that starts with `$zipFiles = ...`. Try submitting `'& foo bar'` in an interactive PowerShell session and you'll see that that what is between `'` and `'` is simply _echoed_.

Comment: `but that results in 502 Bad Gateway errors.` -- That would indicate to me the curl command is executing, but the server is responding with an error, perhaps due to the parameters you're specifying. Maybe the file you're trying to use is too big or malformed, or maybe the URL is bad. If you can, maybe check the server logs surrounding the 502 error. Additionally, it may be of troubleshooting value to try replacing with a simple curl command just to verify it works... for example, try to curl a well-known server like `{ & "$CURL_PATH" "-verbose" "https://httpbin.org/status/200" }` or similar.

Comment: I’m beginning to think that I’d be better off just wrapping the call to curl in a PS script and do it that way within the Foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.  The issue seems to be with how GitLab CI/CD parses the script, so I've spread it across multiple lines like so (using the vertical bar character as per GitLab docs):

```
- |
  $zipFiles | ForEach-Object {
    '& "$CURL_PATH" "-verbose" "-u$ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIAL" "-T$($_.FullName)" "$ARTIFACTORY_URL/$($_.Name)"'
  }
```

and it now works fine.

Comment: So it is _GitLab_ that removes the `'` around the Curl command line before PowerShell sees it? (As noted, in _PowerShell_ a `'...'` token is a _verbatim string literal_ whose value is simply _echoed_). 
What special characters, specifically, require this `'...'` enclosure in GitLab? This looks like a YAML block scalar, but with regular YAML parsing the `'` characters would _not_ be removed. A link to the relevant docs would be helpful.