# Powershell -- how to minimize the console the script is running in while sitting in a loop?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is in my startup:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
```

Note, the script itself is not in startup. Rather in \Startup\ is a shortcut to the script. The shortcut is to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File C:\develop\utils\powershell\converter.ps1
```

and it sits in a loop all day, waiting for events. This is the loop:

```
try {
    # At the end of the script... 
    while ($true) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds .2
    }    
}
catch {}
Finally {
    # Work with CTRL + C exit too !
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $eventname 
}
```

Works great.

But when I log in, there is that command box....

How do I get the script to be exactly what it is, but minimized?  (Or even better,,, sit in the tray... but only if that is easy! What I mean here is: Ideally it wouldn't even be in my alt-tab window sequence... but I could terminate it if I needed to....)

I should further note that the script has to be in my user session, as the events it feeds from are triggered by me as I use other apps. (IOW: Putting it in task scheduler is not an option.)

Comment: Log in? To where? How is the script being called/ran?

Comment: do you have your PS1s associated to PowerShell/Pwsh.exe? Does it really run just placing your script in that location? I only ask since .ps1's are associate with text files by default. Could you maybe create a shortcut to your ps1 (*place your ps1 elsewhere*), place the shortcut it in that location, and call on your ps1 from the shortcut using: `powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden ....`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thank you! OP enhanced to engage your question. (And thank you for pushing me to be more detailed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update*: The following instructions work as advertised, but you state that you were aware of this approach, and that your only problem was that the styling of File Explorer's GUI in *Windows 11* may *falsely* suggest that the window-style dropdown list (field `Run` in a shortcut file's Properties dialog) is *disabled*.

---

Here's how to run your script *minimized* on startup, via the user-specific `"$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"` folder.

- Move your script file, say `foo.ps1` *out of* the startup folder,<sup>[1]</sup> say to your *desktop*.
- In its place, create a *shortcut file* (`.lnk`) that calls your script file with its window minimized:

  - To do this interactively, via File Explorer's `New > Shortcut` shortcut-menu command:

    - Paste the following target command and submit:

      ```
      powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\foo.ps1"
      ```
    - Type a file name (`.lnk` will be appended, though that extension is by default hidden in File Explorer) and submit.
    - Open the Properties dialog for the newly created file and, in field `Run`, select `Minimized`, then submit.

---

<sup>[1] As [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) points out,  `.ps1` files are *not* executed by default when placed in the startup folder or double-clicked in File Explorer (instead, they are opened *for editing*). However, it is possible to reconfigure a system to do that - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245206/45375). Still, that wouldn't give you control over the script's window state when placed directly in the startup folder.</sup>

Comment: Man, I know about that option. But on Windows11, the explorer GUI is messed up. They made too many things understated. (Like alt-tab, the highlight is too faint.) I looked on the shortcut properties, but the Win11 styling has the combobox selector so understated that it appears to be disabled.

Comment: Understood, @JonesomeReinstateMonica - I've added a clarification at the top of the answer.