# Newbie powershell argument issues

Tags: powershell, datetime, command-line-arguments

I made powershell script that [1] accepts 2 arguments (aka parameters), [2] changes a file's modified date & time, and [3] writes something to host.  The following command line works just fine in the powershell console, but triggers an error message when I run the same command line in a Windows cmd prompt (DOS) Window:

```
E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\Change_DateTime_for_test1.bat_and_Hello_world_with_2_named_args_aaa.ps1 -dateTimeVarArg "01/11/2005 06:01:36" -file_dateTimeMod_fullname "E:\Apps\Delete01\test1.bat"
```

The following is the coding for the powershell script to which I gave the long name, 'Change_DateTime_for_test1.bat_and_Hello_world_with_2_named_args_aaa.ps1':

```
param ( [string]$dateTimeVarArg,  [string]$file_dateTimeMod_fullname)
Get-ChildItem  $file_dateTimeMod_fullname | % {$_.LastWriteTime = $dateTimeVarArg}
#Get-ChildItem  "E:\Apps\Delete01\test1.bat" | % {$_.LastWriteTime = $dateTimeVarArg}
$strString = "Hello World"
write-host $strString


function ftest{
$test = "Test"
write-host $test
}

ftest
```

When I run the command line shown above in a Windows DOS command prompt setting, I get the following error message:

```
Exception setting "LastWriteTime": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
At E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\Change_DateTime_for_test1.bat_and_Hello_world_with_1_named_arg_aaa.ps1:6 char:50
+ ... "E:\Apps\Delete01\test1.bat" | % {$_.LastWriteTime = $dateTimeVarArg}
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

I would like to know [1] how to alter the command line shown above (which works fine in the powershell console) so that it works in a Windows DOS command prompt setting, and [2] where I can learn more about why my command line triggers errors, and how to avoid them.
According to the output from the command "Get-Host | Select-Object Version", I am running version. 5.1.19041.1682.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: instead of hoping that the automatic type conversion works the way you want ... EXPLICITLY do it. take a look at `[datetime]::ParseExact()` and the other method for converting a _date string_ to a _datetime object_.

Comment: As an aside: I assume mean `cmd.exe`, the legacy shell also known as Command Prompt. (DOS hasn't been in the picture since the first version of Windows NT, which all Windows versions since derive from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By default, you can *not* directly *execute* PowerShell scripts (`.ps1` files) from `cmd.exe`, the Windows legacy shell, or from *outside* PowerShell altogether**.

- Attempting to do so opens the script file *for editing* instead, as does double-clicking `.ps1` files from File Explorer / the desktop.

**Executing `.ps1` scripts from outside PowerShell itself requires use of the PowerShell CLI** ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+), which in your case translates to a call such as (additional CLI parameters may be called for):

```sh
powershell.exe -File E:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\Change_DateTime_for_test1.bat_and_Hello_world_with_2_named_args_aaa.ps1 -dateTimeVarArg "01/11/2005 06:01:36" -file_dateTimeMod_fullname "E:\Apps\Delete01\test1.bat"
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

The fact that you *were* able to execute your `.ps1` from `cmd.exe` suggests that you changed the file-type definition for such files to execute via `powershell.exe` instead.

The fact that the *arguments* you tried to pass to the script were *ignored* - as implied by the error message you got - suggests that you used File Explorer's `Open with` shortcut-menu command to choose to open all `.ps1` files with `powershell.exe`; said method does *not* support argument-passing.

There *is* a way to change the file-type definition to support argument-passing too, and it is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245206/45375) (section "Programmatic method").

Generally, however, I suggest *not* applying this customization, especially in batch files that must also be run by other users / on other machines, which cannot be expected to have the same customization in place.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for the referral to the Programmatic method.  I can't wait to look it up.  I hope it explains the [datetime]::ParseExact() stuff that Lee_Daily was kind enough to mention (alas, I haven't been able to figure out yet what he was referring to).  I tried to buy you a few cups of coffee, but I couldn't see the captcha that prevented me from doing it.  Can you help me with that? Is it possible for me to give you my email address?

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful, @MarcB.Hankin; my pleasure. What Lee recommended was to validate the `$dateTimeVarArg` value up front, via `[datetime]::ParseExact()`, to ensure that it is recognized as a date. However, you can more simply ensure this by typing your parameters as `[datetime]`; that is, replace `[string] $dateTimeVarArg` with `[datetime] $dateTimeVarArg`

Comment: As for the CAPTCHA problem, @MarcB.Hankin: unfortunately, I  have no idea what the problem is - perhaps trying with a different browser helps? But, no worries if you can't get it to work: donations are completely optional, and do I appreciate the thought.