# Powershell Script only opens as a .txt file when run

Tags: powershell

Hi I have a script on a memory stick that I want to be able to run in cmd line before a computer has windows fully installed. (the stage just after you've connected to a network).

Cmd used to run the script.

```
Start > Run D:\pscript\Intune.ps1
```

This only opens a .txt file, while researching I've found that the reason this happens is due to security, is there anyway to override this bar changing the default file type out.

Comment: `powershell -File D:\pscript\Intune.ps1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike batch files (`.cmd`, `.bat`) associated with `cmd.exe` (the legacy Command Prompt), **PowerShell's `.ps1` script files are by default *not* directly executable from *outside* PowerShell.**

**Instead, they are treated as *documents*** that are by default associated with either Notepad or the (obsolescent) Windows PowerShell ISE, depending on the , and **invoking them therefore *opens them for editing***, which applies to the following contexts:

- Invoking a `.ps1` file from `cmd.exe`
- Invoking a `.ps1` file from Start Menu's `Run` dialog, as in your case (which you can invoke with <kbd>WinKey+R</kbd>, for instance)
- Opening (double-clicking) a `.ps1` file from File Explorer or Desktop.

---

**To execute a `.ps1` script from *outside* PowerShell, you must therefore invoke it via PowerShell's *CLI***, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for *Windows PowerShell*, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.

In the simplest case, using Windows PowerShell and the `-File` parameter, as also shown by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) in a comment; see the comments below and the linked docs for additional parameters:

```bash
# Note:
#  * The effective execution policy applies; use -ExecutionPolicy Bypass to bypass.
#  * Profiles are loaded; use -NoProfile to suppress.
#  * The console window auto-closes when the script terminates; use -NoExit
#    to keep the session open.
powershell.exe -File D:\pscript\Intune.ps1
```

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's CLI, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68136128/45375).

---

**It *is* possible - though not advisable - to configure your system to *execute* `.ps1` files by default** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245206/45375).