# PowerShell: how to prevent window from closing and opening again and again to see the error

Tags: windows, powershell

Everytime I try to execute a PowerShell file (it doesn’t matter whether it’s executing with the cmd or opening a file from the desktop) the console starts opening and closing again and again until it is closed forcibly. Moreover, if the program was written directly in the console, then everything runs perfectly.

No matter what code is written in the file it opens and closes all the time without actually running the code.

Last time code was like this:

```
Write-Host "Invalid option. Enter a number from 1 to 5."
```

While in the PowerShell console it responded with “Invalid option. Enter a number from 1 to 5.”  the file just opened, closed and continued to repeat this deadly spiral.

I tried to run it with per-script fixes both with the running from the PowerShell console using -NoExit switch and with the prompt for input to the end of your script file (not at the same time):

```
PowerShell -NoExit "C:\SomeFolder\SomeScript.ps1"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

It didn’t work, the file continued to open and close.

Maybe I need to reinstall the PowerShell, but I don’t have a lot of time and PowerShell itself kind of works, will it really help?

I’d like the PowerShell to work as it should :^(

Comment: Are you trying to execute your scripts by opening (double-clicking) them from File Explorer / the Desktop? Note that by default this only _opens them for editing_. Making them _execute_ instead requires explicit configuration - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245206/45375).