# Get proper startup directory in PowerShell when executed via a shortcut file

Tags: powershell

I have a shortcut file that points to a PowerShell script file that is located in a different directory, and when that PowerShell script is executed via the shortcut file I require to obtain the proper startup directory (the directory where the shortcut file is) to set it in a variable like this:

```
$gamesDirPath = "{Current Shortcut Directory}\Games"
```

None from [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466329/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-location-of-the-current-powershell-script) seems to return the proper directory.

Note that I'm on PowerShell 5.x

Maybe this question would have an easy solution, but I also tried various times to ask to ChatGPT and each time it does not understand well the question, it demands me to set the location of the .lnk file in a variable inside the script!. Weird. Of course the shortcut file can be located anywhere.

Comment: Afaik, there is no way for PowerShell to determine it has been opened by a shortcut and therefore will also not have a way to determine the location of that shortcut. If you are the one who creates that shortcut, you could add a parameter to your PS call to provide the path info.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Any other approach different than calling the script with a path argument?. Maybe using .NET code?.

Comment: Creating a hard-link instead of a shortcut file solves my problem without requiring code modifications, but I would like to rely in shortcut files for comfort.

Comment: Use an Environmental variable.  Create the variable when games are installed.

Comment: This is a longshot.  Try blanking out the StartIn directory field inside the shortcut file itselr.  You access the shortcut properties by right clicking on the shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [stackprotector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11942268/stackprotector) notes, **an executable launched from a shortcut file (`.lnk`) knows nothing about the latter**.

- It is the [Windows (GUI) shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) (implemented via `explorer.exe` processes) that interprets shortcut files and launches the process for the specified executable (command line), so examining the parent process yields nothing useful.

However, **you can *infer* the directory in which the shortcut is located as long as you don't specify an explicit working directory** (i.e. as long as you leave `Start in:` field in the shortcut-file Properties dialog empty).

- If this condition is met, the [automatic **`$PWD`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) will tell your PowerShell script where the launching shortcut file is located, because **the Windows shell by default makes a shortcut file's own directory the *working directory***.
- Otherwise, read on for an alternative solution, which may be of interest either way.

---

As an **alternative to creating a shortcut file**, consider **creating a *symbolic link* to your script file**, which then causes the latter to see the *link's* full path and directory in the [automatic `$PSCommandPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) and [`$PSScriptRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) variables.

Caveat:

- **Creating symlinks requires *elevation* (running with admin privileges) by default**:
- While there is a way to disable this requirement, doing so requires elevation too (albeit only once) and it is tied to enabling Developer Mode, which is considered a security risk.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - To enable Developer Mode, use the Settings app (`Start-Process ms-setting:developers`)

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministator

New-Item -Force -ItemType SymbolicLink C:\path\to\link.ps1 -Target C:\different-path\to\original.ps1
```

When invoked via symlink `C:\path\to\link.ps1`, `C:\different-path\to\original.ps1` then sees the following values:

- `$PSScriptRoot` is `'C:\path\to'`
- `$PSScriptCommandPath` is `'C:\path\to\link.ps1'`

Note:

- This is **only convenient for invocation from *inside* PowerShell**, given that `.ps1` files aren't directly executable from the outside.
- For **direct execution from *outside* PowerShell**, you again need a shortcut file or you can use File Explorer's shortcut menu, assuming a command to *execute* PowerShell scripts is installed (by default, `.ps1` files are *opened for editing* when double-clicked).
- The caveat is that execution via File Explorer's shortcut menu usually *automatically closes the window* when the script has finished executing. To prevent that, you have two options:

  - Modify the definition of the shortcut-menu command in the registry, so as to include `-NoExit` before `-File` (or `-Command`), which then keeps the window open.
  - Put the following code at the end of your script file, which makes it execute `pause` (wait for a keypress before exiting) *if it finds it was invoked from File Explorer*:

    ```bash
     if ([Environment]::CommandLine -like "*$PSCommandPath*" -and (Get-Process -Id (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $PID").ParentProcessId).Path -like '*\explorer.exe') {
       pause
     }
    ```
- Finally, another option is to make `.ps1` files themselves directly executable from File Explorer and the Desktop, but this option should only be chosen for *your own user account*, given that other uses will not expect this behavior, which can lead to unwanted execution of scripts. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245206/45375).

---

<sup>[1] You get the following warning: "Turning on developer mode, including installing and running apps from outside the Microsoft Store, could expose your device and personal data to security risks or harm your device."</sup>

Comment: $PWD was the key, thanks a lot!. Note that as already said in the answer, the shortcut's "Start in:" value must be EMPTY (an empty value, or two double quotes: ""), because $PWD doesn't point to the shortcut directory if "Start In:" value is the shortcut directory, weird, but it does not work, and if you put ".\" as the "Start In:" value it will point to C:windows\System32. So leave empty the "Start In:" value.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @ElektroStudios. It seems that the working directory of the Windows shell process that launches a shortcut itself defaults to `C:windows\System32`, so that's what you get when you specify `.` or ``.\``. In other words: it only ever makes sense to fill this field with an _absolute_ path.