# PowerShell script works in ISE but unexpectedly exits when invoked via File Explorer's shortcut menu

Tags: powershell, output, contextmenu, microsoft-file-explorer

I'm currently trying to write a script and I'm relatively new to PowerShell:

```
function RunScript {
    # Prompt the user for their username
    $username = Read-Host "Enter your username"

    # Prompt the user for their password
    $password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter your password"

    # Prompt the user for the worker ID
    $workerId = Read-Host "Enter the ID"

    # Create a PSCredential object using the provided username and password
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

    # Create a new PSSession using the provided credential
    $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "LINK/PowerShell/" -Credential $credential

    # Import the PSSession
    Import-PSSession $session

    # Get the AD user and their group membership, then retrieve the distinguished names of the distribution groups
    $groups = Get-ADUser -Identity $workerId | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName | Get-DistributionGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Return the output of the last command
    return $groups
}

# Run the script and store the output
$output = RunScript

# Output the result
Write-Output $output
```

###### ISSUE

The script works well in the ISE, but when I right-click on the file in File Explorer and run it with PowerShell and I input the username, password and workerid, it takes a bit, and then I just see the script outputting tons of users data and then the window closes.
It's like the command is not working correctly.

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: Okay i think see the issue... Now i can see all the data being output it looks like its not being formatted correctly. Is it possible that setting $output = runscript might change the way output looks? I mean the script works in ISE but in powershell itself it doesnt output correctly.

Comment: I would like it to output as the command shows like sort of  table 
x | x | x | x

Comment: To correctly say, i noticed that the output its actually displaying all the attributes of each group that the user is part of...

Comment: Don't use ISE, use literally any other text editor, If you're in an environment with not many resources, still write your script elsewhere and when you're ready test it in a PowerShell terminal. Get used to using the terminal and save yourself the headaches!

Comment: @LuisHernandez Can you provide a sample of the output, not sure what you are referring to. If you want to show certain attributes you can use `Select-Object` again to get the attributes you want. `$groups | Select attribute1, attribute2` etc if you want a nice formatted table you can use `Format-Table -Autosize`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue I was experiencing with my PowerShell script. The problem was related to how the script handled sessions and outputs differently in the PowerShell ISE compared to the standard PowerShell console. Here's the revised version of the script that works effectively in both environments:

```
# Get user credentials
$ExchangeServerURL = "http://your-exchange-server-url/PowerShell/"
$UserCredential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your credentials"
if ($null -eq $UserCredential) {
    Write-Host "No credentials entered. Exiting script."
    exit
}

# Establish a session with the Exchange server
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $ExchangeServerURL -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking | Out-Null

# Main loop for user input and group retrieval
while ($true) {
    $userId = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User ID (or 'exit' to quit)"
    if ($userId -eq 'exit') { break }

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($userId)) {
        Write-Host "Invalid input. Please enter a User ID." -ForegroundColor Red
        continue
    }

    try {
        $groups = Get-ADUser -Identity $userId -ErrorAction Stop |
                  Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership |
                  Select-Object -Property Name, GroupCategory, GroupScope |
                  Format-Table -AutoSize

        if ($groups) {
            Write-Host "Groups for user $userId:" -ForegroundColor Green
            $groups
        } else {
            Write-Host "No groups found for user $userId." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error fetching groups for user $userId. Please try again." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

# Close the session
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

This revised script addresses the original issues by:

1. Simplifying credential input with a check to exit the script if no credentials are entered.
2. Properly establishing and closing the session with the Exchange server, which is crucial for script stability.
3. Handling outputs correctly to avoid overwhelming data display, especially when not using PowerShell ISE.
4. Improving error handling for better clarity and user experience.

This version works reliably both in PowerShell ISE and when executed directly from the File Explorer. Hopefully, this solution can help others facing similar issues.

Comment: This may solve your specific problem, but it doesn't address the question that you asked, and is therefore likely to cause confusion in future readers. What you did ask about was why the window closes when the script is executed _via File Explorer's shortcut menu_. Your revised script too would automatically close on completion, and given that the data being retrieved isn't stored anywhere, invoking your script this way would be pointless. The "especially when not using PowerShell ISE" part is confusing too.

Answer (score 0):

**Executing a PowerShell script from File Explorer, via its shortcut menu**, unfortunately **does *not* keep the console window** that the script runs in **open**.

Thus, in order **to ensure that you at least *see the output* from scripts executed this way**, you have two options:

- For any given script, place something like `Read-Host 'Press Enter to exit.'` at the end of the script, to prevent immediate closing of the window on exit.
- More fundamentally, you can modify the definition of the shortcut-menu command in the registry to:

  - either: automatically execute this `Read-Host` call after every script invocation
  - or: keep the console window open until explicitly closed, by entering a persistent, interactive session.
  - Both approaches are shown below.

---

###### Modifying the `Run with PowerShell` File Explorer shortcut-menu command to keep the window open:

- The following applies to:

  - Windows 11
  - Windows PowerShell, the *legacy*, Windows-only PowerShell edition (as opposed to the install-on-demand, cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition).

**Instructions**:

- Step 1: Define the new command line.

  - Note:

    - Both alternatives below cause PowerShell's [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) to be loaded on invocation; to avoid that, precede `-File` or `-Command` with `-NoProfile`.
  - If you want to **enter an interactive session after executing a script**, place the  `-NoExit` switch of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, before the `-File` parameter (`-NoLogo` is also specified to suppress the copyright message):

    ```
    $newCmdLine = '"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoExit -File "%1"'
    ```
  - If you'd rather **just wait for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before the window closes**, use the `-Command` CLI parameter and append the `Read-Host` command:

    ```
    $newCmdLine = '"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "& \"%1\"; Read-Host ''Press Enter to exit.''"'
    ```
- Step 2: Write the new command line to the registry:

  - To modify the definition ***system-wide*** (for *all* users), run the following, which **requires *elevation*** (running as admin):

    ```
    #requires -RunAsAdministrator

    Set-ItemProperty registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\Windows.PowerShell.Run\Command '(Default)' $newCmdLine
    ```
  - To modify the definition **for the *current user only*** - which doesn't require elevation - run:

    ```
    $regKey = New-Item -Force registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\Windows.PowerShell.Run\Command
    Set-ItemProperty "registry::$regKey" '(Default)' $newCmdLine
    ```