# How to Read the Shortcut Itself Not the Target of the LNK?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read the LNK file not the target of the shortcut. The following PowerShell code reads the target of the shortcut into the variable rather than the shortcut file itself.

Here is the code that I used to create the LNK:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Name "test.lnk" -Value "C:\Windows\System32\alg.exe"
```

Here is the code to read the LNK:

```
$file_data = Get-Content -Encoding Byte $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\test.lnk
$encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($file_data)
```

Here is the contents of the variable `$encoded`

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $encoded
TVqQAAMAAAA
```

I have truncated the content here, but `TVqQAAMAAAA` is base64 for the first bytes of a Windows PE file: `MZ.....`.

Here is the contents of the variable `$file_data`:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $file_data
77
90
144
```

I have truncated this, but `77 90` is enough to see that this is `MZ` which is the magic bytes for a PE executable that is the target of the LNK not the LNK itself.

The first characters of the resulting data should be `TAAAAAEUA` in base64 or `76 0 0 0 1 20 2 0` in integers if this has read what I need. These are the magic bytes for a LNK file.

How do I read the bytes of the shortcut itself into the variable?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce what you state in Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core. If you are seeing something like this, it is not a real link file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your later edits inadvertently changed the premise of your question: you're confusing *shortcut files* (`.lnk`) - a Windows (GUI) shell *file format* - with *symbolic links* - a *file-system-level* redirection to another file.**

**What your `New-Item` call creates is a *symbolic link*, not a shortcut file, even though you happened to choose the same filename extension (`.lnk`)** - in other words: the resulting file-system entry is *not* valid shortcut file, and, due it being a *symbolic link*, accessing it with `Get-Content` indeed transparently redirects to the *target* of the symbolic link and reads *its* content.

- To determine a given symbolic link's target path, you needn't read its *content*, just use something like `(Get-Item $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\mylink).Target`

This answer addresses the *original* form of your question, relating to - **true - shortcut files (`.lnk`)**, which **can *not* be created with [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item)** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47743337/45375) for how to create them via COM):

---

> `$file_data = Get-Content -Encoding Byte $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\test.lnk`

*does* read the `.lnk` file *itself* (into an `[object[]]` array of `[byte]` instances), and *not* whatever executable the `.lnk` file happens to point to.

Unlike with *symbolic links* or other NTFS *reparse points*, *no* transparent redirection happens when a shortcut file (`.lnk`) is targeted, because to the *file system* such files are just regular files. It is the Windows (GUI) *shell* that interprets such files as pointing elsewhere (to an executable with arguments or to a document).

---

As an aside:

- A more efficient way to read a file as raw bytes is to combine `-Encoding Byte` with `-Raw` in a  [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) call, which reads the file as a whole *in a single operation* and returns a *strongly typed* `[byte[]]` array.
- Also note that in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* `-AsByteStream` must be used in lieu of `-Encoding Byte`.